# read values from a variable of Type system.string

Tags: powershell

I had a variable `$gh` with the below output. I mean when I type `$gh`. I will get values like below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>$gh

No.  Department Name          Environment Id           Location Name   Ready Status          Machine Pure Status   
1    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY04        Environment-k2345             EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
2    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY03        Environment-k89               EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
3    EMA-EFT-JIU-FC           Environment-k3456             EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
4    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08        Environment-k7890             EMA               Not Ready                UNKNOWN       
5    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY02-ED      Environment-k9                EMA               Enabled                  GREEN
```

The type of `$gh` is `System.String` as indicated by `$gh.GetType().fullname`.

I would like to get values from department name and environment id into a array or variable so that if i query about EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08 i can get environment id Environment-k7890.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A different approach is to split your table into columns
  by replacing two or more spaces with a comma
- as you have proper headers you can then `ConvertFrom-Csv` and
- `Select-Object` the wanted properties

---

```
$gh = "No.  Department Name          Environment Id           Location Name   Ready Status          Machine Pure Status   
1    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY04        Environment-k2345             EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
2    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY03        Environment-k89               EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
3    EMA-EFT-JIU-FC           Environment-k3456             EMA               Enabled                  GREEN         
4    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08        Environment-k7890             EMA               Not Ready                UNKNOWN       
5    EMA-MET-CAT5-KY02-ED      Environment-k9                EMA               Enabled                  GREEN        
"

$Data = $gh -split [environment]::newline | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace ' {2,}',','
} | ConvertFrom-csv | Select-Object "Department Name","Environment Id"

$Data | Where-Object 'Department Name' -eq 'EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08'
```

Sample output:

```
Department Name   Environment Id
---------------   --------------
EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08 Environment-k7890
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have two question 1:- How to convert the system.string to PSObject. for example:- to print or retrieve a selected value.  In the above table, $gh is having the table output so if i print or export-csv i am not getting the table format but the export-csv is giving "Length" "750".. question 2:- The column headings "Department Name"/"Environment Id" is having spaces in the names, how to read headings even though it is having spaces...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the department name and environment Id have no spaces in them, I would use a regular expression (regex) looking for the pattern at the start of a line (number, spaces, name, spaces, id) and put them into a hashtable.

```
PS C:\> $lookup = @{}
PS C:\> [regex]::matches($gh, '(?m)^\d+\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)').foreach{
    $lookup[$_.groups[1].value] = $_.groups[2].value
}
PS C:\> $lookup

Name                           Value
----                           -----
EMA-EFT-JIU-FC                 Environment-k3456
EMA-MET-CAT5-KY02-ED           Environment-k9
EMA-MET-CAT5-KY04              Environment-k2345
EMA-MET-CAT5-KY03              Environment-k89
EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08              Environment-k7890


PS C:\> $lookup['EMA-MET-CAT5-KY08']
Environment-k7890
```